# Outlook - OAuth 2 - Fail to retrieve access token, grant_type=password is unsupported, only authorization_code and refresh_token are

Tags: php, azure, oauth, outlook

I'm currently trying to implement a way to synchronize my PHP App calendar with the Outlook calendar of my clients, using Azure API.
I use OAuth2 and the custom [Microsoft provider by Steven Maguire.](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft)
I currently run in an issue where I get an error in my response :

**{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"The provided value for the input parameter 'grant_type' is not valid. Expected values are the following: 'authorization_code', 'refresh_token'."}**

I'm having trouble understanding why the grant_type password is not supported, even though it says on the documentation of Azure that it is.

The request looks like this :

**client_id=44bef79b-**********************&client_secret=H****************&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.123%2Fmapeyral%2Fcalendarsync.php&grant_type=password&username=******************&password=***********&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20Calendars.ReadWrite**

The Authorize url used is : https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf
as defined in the Steven Maguire provider.
The header contains the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded (I've seen a lot of post where this was what caused the error).

Some of my code :

```
$this->provider = new Microsoft([
      'clientId'                => MicrosoftGraphConstants::CLIENT_ID,
      'clientSecret'            => MicrosoftGraphConstants::CLIENT_SECRET,
      'redirectUri'             => MicrosoftGraphConstants::REDIRECT_URI,
      'urlAuthorize'            => MicrosoftGraphConstants::AUTHORITY_URL . MicrosoftGraphConstants::AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT,
      'urlAccessToken'          => MicrosoftGraphConstants::AUTHORITY_URL . MicrosoftGraphConstants::TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => MicrosoftGraphConstants::RESOURCE_ID,
      'scope'                  => MicrosoftGraphConstants::SCOPES
    ]);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && !isset($_GET['code']))
    {
      // Try getting access token from Database
      $workingAccount = $GLOBALS['AppUI']->getState('working_account');
      if (isset($workingAccount))
      {
        // DB access
        $DB = new DatabaseConnection();
        $dbAccess = $DB->getConnection();

        $contactData = DBUserUtils::getContactDataFromEmail($GLOBALS['AppUI']->getState('working_account'), $dbAccess);

        // If at least one user contact found
        if (!is_null($contactData))
        {
          // If has refresh token => fill session variables using refresh token
          if (!is_null($contactData['contact_refreshToken']))
          {
            log_msg('debug.log', 'Has refresh token');
            $GLOBALS['AppUI']->setState('preferred_username', $contactData['contact_email']);
            $GLOBALS['AppUI']->setState('given_name', $contactData['contact_first_name']." ".$contactData['contact_last_name']);
            // Get new tokens
            $newAccessToken = $this->provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
              'refresh_token' => $contactData['contact_refreshToken']
            ]);

            // Update tokens and DB
            $GLOBALS['AppUI']->setState('refresh_token', $newAccessToken->getRefreshToken());
            $GLOBALS['AppUI']->setState('access_token', $newAccessToken->getToken());

            DBOAuthUtils::updateTokenForUser($contactData['contact_id'], $GLOBALS['AppUI']->getState('refresh_token'), $dbAccess);

            $this->redirectTo($redirectURL);
          }
          else
          {
             $this->getAccessToken();

          }
        }
        else
        {
           $this->getAccessToken();
        }
      }
      else
      {
         $this->getAccessToken();
      }

function getAccessToken(){
 $accessToken = $this->provider->getAccessToken('password', [
              'username' => '*************',
              'password' => '********',
              'scope'    => MicrosoftGraphConstants::SCOPES
            ]);
}
```

During the first try it doesn't pass the if (isset($workingAccount)) condition (as expected) and go straight to the last else.
Code is a bit ugly for now but I don't think it has an impact on my problem.

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks

Edit : added code

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: It's a sample of my code but it's done. The database stuff is pretty useless because it's for when a user already authenticated himself

Comment: Right, so you are in fact specifically telling the lib to use the password grant type. As the error messages states, this is not supported by them. The only one allowed is the authorization_code (ignoring refresh, which is something you'll need to look at later) type for which there is an example on the readme of the repo link you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That helped me, the problem was that I need to use Azure Active Directory and not Azure AD 2.0.
Problem solved !

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so that others can benefit from it. Thanks

Comment: @iddys can you please describe it more, how to change from Ad2.0 to Azure Active Directory?

Comment: @Gaurav infortunately for you I didn't used Azure Active Directory in the end, I found another way to do what I wanted to do with AD 2.0, so I can't help you :/ Good luck !

Comment: @Gaurav infortunately for you I didn't used Azure Active Directory in the end, I found another way to do what I wanted to do with AD 2.0, so I can't help you :/ Good luck !